# How to know programmatically whether Message Queueing is enabled on the machine or not?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I know that when I try to create new `MessageQueue`, system throws `InvalidOperationException` if the Message Queuing is not enabled.

But how to know **programmatically** whether Message Queueing is enabled on the machine or not?
I am using C# 2.0 & C# 4.0 in two different code bases.

Comment: You indeed answered your question, just try this

try
{
 //create or open a MessageQueue
}
catch (InvalidOperationException )
{
 // is not enabled  
}

Comment: Using exceptions to detect state/information is a bad practice unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the **System.ServiceProcess** for this one, but first you need to add reference to your project the `Service.ServiceProcess`, and you can retrieve all the services and get their status like this:

```
List<ServiceController> services = ServiceController.GetServices().ToList();
ServiceController msQue = services.Find(o => o.ServiceName == "MSMQ");
if (msQue != null) {
    if (msQue.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) { 
        // It is running.
    }
} else { // Not installed? }
```

Comment: Excellent ! Accepting as the answer. Modified the exact name of the MSMQ service that OS runs when MSMQ is installed. The `ServiceName` is `MSMQ` on Windows 7 & Windows XP at least.

Answer (score 2):

Answering little late, but if you are scripting fan Powershell is at your help.
To get status update on numbers, use following script:

```
$queues = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue
$queues | ft -property Name,MessagesInQueue
```

This will show you name of queue and number of items in each queue. Hope this will help someone someday. :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But question was clearly for C# if you see the tags .. :)

Comment: Oops! did not pay attention, but now a days Powershell is so closely knitted in .net framework that it can be invoke natively. #Justsaying

Answer (score 1):

[How to tell if MSMQ is installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-tell-if-msmq-is-installed.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You have answered your own question there: try to create a new MessageQueue, and catch InvalidOperationException.

If you don't get an exception, MQ is enabled; if you get an exception, it's not enabled. (you may dispose of that MessageQueue instance if one was created, as you've only used it for detecting support)